# Reorder UICollectionView Section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Is there a possibility to drag and drop whole `UICollectionViewSection`. I have 6 sections with reusable header and 2 cells in that Section. I want to reorder the CollectionView by selecting the Header of that section.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath,toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let temp1 = self.embedded.embeddedItemsArray.count
    var temp2 = Array(arrayLiteral: temp1)
}
```

I am not able to select the `UICollectionViewSection` and drag and drop. I can select the cells inside the header but not the Header/Section itself.